# HTML Java applet param security permissions

Tags: html, parameters, applet

See this HTML snippet

```
<APPLET ID="SmartCard" codebase="." code="SmartCard.class" width=1 height=1>
<param name="permissions" value="all-permissions">
</APPLET>
```

I want to specify only this specific permission :

> javax.smartcardio.CardPermission

In the file .java.policy I use the syntax

```
grant {
    permission javax.smartcardio.CardPermission "*", "*";
};
```

Which is the right syntax for the APPLET PARAM value ?

NOTE : The applet is just a plain CLASS file.
I will use a manifest and JAR files only if they are the only solution to set javax.smartcardio.CardPermission.

Comment: *"Which is the right syntax for the APPLET PARAM value ?"* There isn't one. *"The applet is just a plain CLASS file. I will use a manifest and JAR files only if they are the only solution to set javax.smartcardio.CardPermission."* A **digitally signed** Jar is the only option, but it does not offer such fine grained permissions. It will be necessary to specify `all-permissions`. **But** see [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).

Comment: I know about java applets destiny. Where did you read about "does not offer such fine grained permissions" ?